# Google Analytics filter with multiple conditions

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I would like to exclude all traffic that has these three conditions:

Mobile traffic, that was a direct hit(has no referrer), on uri: '/'.

Is this possible in Google Analytics? In the filters section I only saw the option to add filters separately, not as a combined condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using advanced segments instead of a filter.

[Google Analytics Separating Tablet and Mobile Traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059942/google-analytics-separating-tablet-and-mobile-traffic) has an answer from [chsweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360981/chsweb) that gives an example of doing so:

> To separate Tablet traffic from your site's Mobile traffic, you need to create a new "Advanced Segment."
>
> 1. Log in to Google Analytics
> 2. Go to the customer profile you want mobile stats for
> 3. Click the "Advanced Segments" link towards to top of the page (in the gray bar)
> 4. Click the "+ New Custom Segment" button
> 5. Enter a name for this segment, e.g., Mobile (not tablet)
> 6. Configure this: [Include] Mobile (Including Tablet) [Exactly matching] Yes
> 7. Click "Add 'OR' statement
> 8. Configure this: [Exclude] Tablet [Exactly matching] Yes
> 9. Click the "Save Segment" button
> 10. Return to the "Reporting" are in Google Analytics
> 11. Click 'Advanced Segments' again, choose your new "Mobile (not tablet)" custom segment
> 12. Click Apply
> 13. There's your metrics for mobile devices that are not tablets